# JMeter won't add parameters from blazemeter

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

The parameters of a Request I recorded with Blazemeter won't add to the request in JMeter.

The body of the request looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to add those params automatically?

The request is an Ajax request and Angularjs is involved.

Comment: Do you mean the generated script by Blazemeter plugin does not contain the parameters of the query you show ?

Comment: What do you mean? How did you recorded it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to record request with Jmeter only.
If it will nothelp try to add these parameters manually.